# Laravel Storage: Image Not Showing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-storage

I'm working with Laravel latest version and I want to show an image like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$media->med_path) }}" alt="Thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: auto;">
```

And when I see the source code it adds this value to **`src`** attribute of image tag:

`http://localhost:8000/storage/public/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg`

But the image itself not showing up somehow:

[image]

Here is also the value of variable (`$media->med_path`) in the DB:

```
public/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg
```

However I have already ran the command `php artisan storage:link` and the links are already exists via this `filesystems.php` config file:

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        ...

        'links' => [
            public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        ],
```

And the image already exists in this directory of my project:

```
-project
     -storage
           -app
                -public
                     -medias
                          -jpg
                               -57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg
```

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue and show the image properly?

Comment: Try `{{ url($media->med_path) }}"`

Comment: http://localhost:8000/storage/public/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg storage/*app*/public

Comment: @HerrysAghistaRachman I didn't understand what you're sayin'

Comment: your pathing is missing the app folder if you seen your link,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reach to storage from public link from
`http://localhost:8000/storage/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg`

you shouldn't get storage directly
when you store image url in DB store link like
`storage/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg`
and when you want to get it in blade get it like this:

```
<img src="{{ asset($media->med_path) }}" alt="" />
```

Comment: I tried the `http://localhost:8000/storage/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg` at my browser and got 404 not found

Comment: Are you serving your project with 'php artisan serve'?                     If you don't you can get the image by [http://localhost/path-to-your-project-root-folder/public/storage/medias/jpg/57N8MJmsp2y8P0aexysV_200x200.jpg ]

Comment: This problem is already solve, take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77357415/phpstorm-does-not-seem-to-be-recognizing-the-php-service-class